# Support URL in iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I am Submitting my App to AppStore now.

Can I use my Facebook profile URL in the support URL field in the iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. I do this for all my apps and I never had Apple message about that.

Comment: How long time will it take for Apple to Accept/Reject my application?

Comment: Between about 4 and 7 days. Sometimes more. It depends

Comment: Now takes  only about 8 hours for validation :)

Comment: Are `mailto:` links (eg. `mailto:name@example.com`) also valid?

Comment: @FiliusPatris nop

Comment: But another option: Make a Google Form in Google Drive and make a link to it. Worked for me (just don't ever delete the Form file)

Answer (score 1):

I just got rejected for using FB:

Guideline 1.5 - Safety - Developer Information

The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, https://www.facebook.com/ThanhTuHackintosh, still does not properly navigate to the intended destination.